# Simple adding spaces between variables in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I searched but found many things for removing space. I'm brand spanking new to python and trying to write a simple program that asks for first name, last name and then does the greeting. No matter how many spaces I put in between name + last on the print function line it keeps mashing the first and last name together.

```
name = input ("What is your first name?: ")

last = input ("what is your last name?: ")

print ('Nice to meet you,' name + last)
```

It outputs:

What is your first name?:Jessie

What is your last name?: Jackson

Nice to meet you, JessieJackson

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry we went out of town unexpectedly after I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get the wanted output:

**Concentrating strings**
If you want to concentrate your string you use the `+` operator.
It will concentrate your strings EXACTLY the way you provide them in your code.
Example:

```
>>> stringA = 'This is a'
>>> stringB = 'test'
>>> print(stringA + stringB)
'This is atest'

>>> print(stringA + ' ' + stringB)
'This is a test'
```

**Printing on the same line**

If you simply want to print multiple strings on the same line you can provide your strings to the `print` function as arguments seperated with a `,`
Example:

```
>>> print('I want to say:', stringA, stringB)
I want to say: This is a test
```

**Formatting strings**

The most used way is string formatting. This can be done in two ways:
- Using the `format` function
- Using the 'old' way with `%s`
Example:

```
>>> print('Format {} example {}'.format(stringA, stringB))
Format This is a example test

>>> print('Old: %s example %s of string formatting' % (stringA, stringB))
Old: This is a example test of string formatting
```

Of course those examples can be combined in any way you want.
Example:

```
>>> stringC = 'normally'
>>> print((('%s strange {} no one ' % stringA) + stringC).format(stringB), 'uses')
This is a strange test no one normally uses
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I'm not sure why I had it in my head that I had to concatenate the strings instead of just printing them on the same line. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` to append a string literal containing a space like this:

```
print ('Nice to meet you, ' + name + ' ' + last)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to concatenate them together you could use:

```
print("Nice to meet you, " name, last)
```

outputting:

> Nice to meet you, Jessie Jackson

This is because `+` concatenates strings but `,` prints them on the same line, but automatically spacing them because they are seperate entities.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize it was so simple. I thought I HAD to use the +. I feel silly now